set faust-streaming table changelog flush
Using faust-streaming with tables and have a set up where an app creates objects by reading from a main input topic.
When we start the app, or after a rebalance, we have set it to read the main input topic from the zero offset so all object can be created if needed. This ensures all objects are created and the devices they're responsible for interacting with are being monitored.
The very first time we start, this is easy - everything is new so there is no historical information to worry about, the object is created, the device connected to, updates are sent.
The main app also subscribes to this output (along with those down the pipeline for the proper data analysis) and stores the result in a table so that after a rebalance we can provide the last known state on initialising each object so it can only bother to send data if it's truly new compared to the last known state.
However, we're finding that the table isn't fully up to date after a rebalance for some many tens of seconds. Say one worker dies and the other are assigned new partitions so on reading from the main topic they will have new objects to create. These objects are sometimes not yet in the table so report having no historic data which triggers it to be treated as a brand new device connection which then triggers the sending of a large set of unnecessary data further down the pipeline.
Is there a way to change the table buffer settings to flush the table changelog topic more frequently?
